# buildozer android debug deploy (run)

Tags: eclipse, adb, kivy, android-sdk-2.1

I am currently stuck in deploying an app into into my phone.
The app is part of [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8N_8WkALdE&list=SPdNh1e1kmiPP4YApJm8ENK2yMlwF1_edq). Everything concerning the `main.py` and `buildozer.spec` files is set according this tutorial. The app works just fine when run in Eclipse (though some console "errors").

My phone is a Samsung GT-15500, Android version 2.2.  and i  am also running an apk installer and  [kivy launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kivy.pygame&hl=en).

Additionally inside my phone files `/mnt/sdcard` i cant find a `/kivy` directory in  order to place my app and a simple text file as mentioned [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-your-application-for-the-kivy-launcher).

Anyway, the thing is that both in the tutorial and the kivy docs the following command: ***buildozer android debug deploy run*** fails into my machine. The given error is produced:

```
    # Android packaging done!
# APK Kivyapp1-1.2.0-debug.apk available in the bin directory
# Run '/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/platform-tools/adb devices'
# Cwd None
/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
# Command failed: /home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/platform-tools/adb devices
```

I am suspecting there has something to do with my ADT and SDK tools, configuration etc.

Any suggestions??

Oh and thanks in advance for your time.!

Edit: I am running a Linux Mint 16 distro

Edit2: corrected `main.app` to `main.py` and added info about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything concerning the main.app

Just to be clear, you mean main.py right?

> My phone is a Samsung GT-15500, Android version 2.2. and i am also running an apk installer and kivy launcher.

Have you tried kivy programs in the kivy launcher? Do they work? Phones old enough to use android 2.2 can sometimes have some graphics driver problems or bugs even if they technically meet the kivy requirements.

This wouldn't affect the buildozer compilation though, it's just another thing.

> The given error is produced:

Could you set your log_level to 2 in buildozer.spec (the video covers this), run the build again, and paste the full log here. It isn't possible to debug from that single line.

==============

Edit: Okay, it looks like the apk is actually built correctly, and you should be able to find it in the 'bin' subfolder of wherever you ran buildozer. Assuming that's the case, you can try copying it to your phone some other way (email or whatever should work).

The step that's actually failing is the 'deploy' part that should push the apk to  your device. I don't know what the error is, and I've never seen buildozer complain about curses before, though I guess you could check that you have curses installed?

My best suggestion is to investigate by navigating to the directory with adb in and playing with it manually. You can look up the commands, like `adb install ...` to install an apk to your phone - that's what buildozer tries to do.

You should also check that adb is enabled on your phone.

Comment: 1. yes i meant main.py (edited) 2. No, i haven't, but as you said it shouldn't be a problem to compile 3.`log_level = 2` is on  debug mode already. In which log are you referring?

Comment: Just edited the question, maybe now it is more precise

Comment: I edited my reply to give more suggestions in response to your own edits. However, if other kivy apps do not work, you may find your apk doesn't work anyway.

Comment: The .apk  file is in the `/bin` dir. I have already tried unsuccessfully to  play with straight adb commands from  bash..  Question: What you mean by **curses**  and how to i check adb on phone? It's running on debug mode.

Comment: ok so i managed to copy-paste the app and install it to my phone only to discover what we suspected is right.. _It does not work!_ maybe  its time for a  new phone then.. anyway thumbs up for the feedback i really appreciate it

Comment: Oh dear, sorry about that, it does sound like it's just doesn't quite meet kivy's graphics driver requirements.